# How to initialize a session in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

Upon any incoming connection, so whenever a new computer or a browser connects and a new session cookie is created, I want to initialize a couple of session variables. If I do this:

```
session["authorized"] = False
session["client_id"] = None
session["client_secret"] = None
session["go_id"] = None
session["test_mode"] = None
```

outside of a function decorator, I got this error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
> information about how to avoid this problem.

If I use the `app.before_first_request` decorator, it run the initialization only once for the very first connection/session, but if I connect with another browser, the initialization doesn't happen. That looks like this:

```
@instance.before_first_request
def initialize():
    session["authorized"] = False
    session["client_id"] = None
    session["client_secret"] = None
    session["go_id"] = None
    session["test_mode"] = None
```

If instead I use `before_request`, the initialization happens on each request and the variables are always overridden.

How can I initialize each single session but just once?

Comment: What you're looking for is `before_request` and `after_request` decorator. Try `@instance.before_request`

Comment: Note that the default Flask session is not secure. Don't put something like a `client_secret` in there. Miguel Grinberg has a blog on this topic https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-secure-is-the-flask-user-session

Comment: @PGHE Thank you for this information. This app is just a REST API client and the user has to know the secret in the first place so it's not such a deal but I will remember that and look into Flask-Session.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method works for me

```
if not session.get('authorized'):
   session['authorized'] = False

if not session.get('client_id'):
   session['client_id'] = None

if not session.get('client_secret'):
   session['client_secret'] = None

if not session.get('go_idt'):
   session['go_id'] = None

if not session.get('test_mode'):
   session['test_mode'] = None
```